# Youon digraphs as a single character?

Tags: history, kana

Was there ever any practice of writing youon digraphs as a single character (taking up the same amount of space as a monograph), and if not would that be a good idea?

e.g. ハロｳｨーン or ハロｳｲーン instead of ハロウィーン, where ｳｲ (ｳｨ) would be treated as a single character.

Comment: Someone might have done it for funny effect. Recently, technical difficulty of mixing hankaku kana has been solved for the most part, but I wouldn't recommend it in terms of readability.

Comment: Although it is interesting, I think it is difficult to change the habit familiar to Japanese people. Why don't you think about the idea to express the singular form of "they/their/them/theirs" instead?

Comment: 「キョウモト」（京本）→「ｷｮウモト」「ｷﾖウモト」、「ショウコ」（翔子）→「ｼｮウコ」「ｼﾖウコ」、ってことですよね。。。既に全部半角の場合（eg「ｷｮｳ‌​ﾓﾄ」「ｼｮｳｺ」とか。銀行振り込みとか‌​の。）はどうするんでしょう・・・

Answer (score 2):

There is no such rule in the Japanese grammar and I don't think it would be a good idea. I think it just weird.

Comment: This has nothing to do with grammar.